# How to create a floating button for attachments in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How do create a floating button and animate different options on its button press in Flutter? I am trying to make something like below:

When I try to add multiple floating buttons, I get '`argument for the name floating button action has already been specified`' error

```
    class MyBills extends StatelessWidget {
  MyBills({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  //@override
  //MyBillsPageState createState() => MyBillsPageState();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 20,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return new Container(height: 100, child: BillItem());
        }
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        child: new Icon(Icons.add),
        heroTag: 1,
        onPressed: _addAttachment
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        child: new Icon(Icons.camera),
        heroTag: 2,
        onPressed: _cameraAttachment
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]
or animate floating options [like this](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fcamo.githubusercontent.com%2F0d71fda546fc0aabd5b9e6fa0ea0934dace2c085%2F687474703a2f2f692e67697068792e636f6d2f3236426b4d69723949634168716534454d2e676966&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fmastermoo%2Freact-native-action-button&docid=sycDxFd89UYT2M&tbnid=-nC6Xb2sMwLPgM%3A&vet=1&w=320&h=520&source=sh%2Fx%2Fim)

Comment: Is a [fab_dialer](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_fab_dialer) what you're after? Here's also [a version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46480221/flutter-floating-action-button-with-speed-dial) which doesn't use a package.

Comment: yes.. got it .. !

Answer (score 3):

Give every `FloatingActionButton` a unique `heroTag` tag, and you should be good to go.

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
  heroTag: 0, // you can use any object here
),
```

---

Your solution:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    body: Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
      children: <Widget>[
        ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 20,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return new Container(height: 100, child: BillItem());
            }
        ),
        Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            new FloatingActionButton(child: new Icon(Icons.add), heroTag: 1, onPressed: _addAttachment),
            new FloatingActionButton(child: new Icon(Icons.camera), heroTag: 2, onPressed: _cameraAttachment),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: I gave different heroTag , but I still get the same error.

Comment: I made an edit in my question. See where am I trying to add floating point

Comment: that worked.. but how do I animate and display different options? Other floating buttons should be hidden on initial load of the view

Comment: @DeepakThakur Kindly ask that as a separate question. And don't forget to upvote and accept this answer. Thank you :)

Comment: But the inital part of my question was to animate and display floating buttons only

Comment: What kind of animations are you are looking for?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187407/discussion-between-deepak-thakur-and-copsonroad).