# Multiple floating buttons - Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

it's possible to create a float action button which open more float buttons, and If yes, can you give me a example?

Like these :

[image: FloatActionButton padrão]

[image: múltiplos botões flutuantes]

Comment: Here is what you are exactly looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46480221/flutter-floating-action-button-with-speed-dial

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter floating action button with speed dial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46480221/flutter-floating-action-button-with-speed-dial)

Comment: Hey Blasanka, i found the answer in the comment, using this widget called flutter_speed_dial 1.2.4 https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_speed_dial

Can you reply as a answer for me to close the question and accept your comment as a solution ?

Answer (score 16):

Flutter gives a `named parameter` in Scaffold Widget - ‘floatingActionButton’. And the named parameter `floatingActionButton` shouldn't take only `FloatingActionButton` widget, it should take `Widget` and it does. So you can assign another widget instead of `FloatingActionButton` like as `Column, Row, Stack`. And it works.

```
floatingActionButton: Row(
  children: [
    RaisedButton(child: Text('Button1'), onPressed: (){}),
    RaisedButton(child: Text('Button1'), onPressed: (){}),
  ]
),
```

I just give you a reference example, it will work - you just need to customize the styles and positioning as you want. Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: You need to wrap the `Row` in a `SingleChildScrollView`.

Answer (score 5):

Try This

```
floatingActionButton: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: getImage,
              child: Icon(Icons.camera),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 8,),
            FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: getImage,
              child: Icon(Icons.camera),
            ),
          ],
        )
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the [SpeedDial](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_speed_dial) widget provided by flutter_speed_dial package you can use multiple float button as children of a parent floating action button. You can also add animated icons.

In your pubspec.yaml under dependecies, add:

```
dependencies:
 flutter_speed_dial: ^1.2.5
```

Now you can use the SpeedDial widget in your FAB:

```
floatingActionButton: SpeedDial(

//provide here features of your parent FAB

children: [
        SpeedDialChild(
          child: Icon(Icons.accessibility),
          label: 'First',
          onTap: null,),
        SpeedDialChild(
          child: Icon(Icons.accessibility),
          label: 'Second',
          onTap: null,),
        ...
 ]
),
```