# Why is my FAB speed dial on top of my drawer?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to explore flutter. I managed to edit speed dial from [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_speed_dial_material_design#-readme-tab-) and create a speed dial with my desired rotating animation. But currently i am facing an issue that the FAB will be on top of my drawer when it is opened. I am not sure how to fix this. Please help me.
The FAB is on top of drawer:
[image]

Main:

```
final _drawerNav = Drawer(
    child: Container(
  color: constant.colorPrimary,
  child: ListView(
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 30.0, 10.0, 10.0),
    children: <Widget>[
      UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: constant.colorPrimary),
        accountName: Text("Ashish Rawat",
            style: TextStyle(color: constant.colorWhite)),
        accountEmail: Text("ashishrawat2911@gmail.com",
            style: TextStyle(color: constant.colorWhite)),
        currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
          radius: 100,
          backgroundColor: constant.colorWhite,
          child: Container(
            width: 100,
            child: CircleAvatar(
              radius: 50,
              backgroundColor: constant.colorPrimary,
              child: Text(
                "A",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40.0),
              ),
            ),
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              border: new Border.all(
                color: constant.colorWhite,
                width: 2.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      ListTile(
        leading: Icon(OMIcons.accountCircle, color: constant.colorWhite),
        title: Text(constant.profile,
            style: TextStyle(color: constant.colorWhite)),
        onTap: () {},
      ),
      ListTile(
        leading: Icon(OMIcons.event, color: constant.colorWhite),
        title: Text(constant.calendar,
            style: TextStyle(color: constant.colorWhite)),
        onTap: () {},
      ),
      ListTile(
        leading: Icon(OMIcons.assignment, color: constant.colorWhite),
        title: Text(constant.archive,
            style: TextStyle(color: constant.colorWhite)),
        onTap: () {},
      ),
      ListTile(
        leading: Icon(OMIcons.photo, color: constant.colorWhite),
        title: Text(constant.gallery,
            style: TextStyle(color: constant.colorWhite)),
        onTap: () {},
      ),
      ListTile(
        leading: Icon(OMIcons.exitToApp, color: constant.colorWhite),
        title: Text(constant.signOut,
            style: TextStyle(color: constant.colorWhite)),
        onTap: () {
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              // return object of type Dialog
              return AlertDialog(
                title: new Text("Alert Dialog title"),
                content: new Text("Alert Dialog body"),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  // usually buttons at the bottom of the dialog
                  new FlatButton(
                    child: new Text("Close"),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    ],
  ),
))

_onSpeedDialAction(int selectedActionIndex) {
  print('$selectedActionIndex Selected');
}

Widget _buildFloatingActionButton() {
  final TextStyle customStyle =
      TextStyle(inherit: false, color: Colors.black);
  final icons = [
    SpeedDialAction(child: Icon(OMIcons.photo)),
    SpeedDialAction(child: Icon(OMIcons.assignment)),
    SpeedDialAction(child: Icon(OMIcons.event)),
  ];

  return SpeedDialFloatingActionButton(
    actions: icons,
    screenColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
    useRotateAnimation: false,
    onAction: _onSpeedDialAction,
    controller: _controller,
    isDismissible: true,
    backgroundColor: constant.colorPrimary,
    foregroundColor: constant.colorWhite,
  );
}

return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(_title, style: TextStyle(color: constant.colorPrimary)),
      iconTheme: IconThemeData(
        color: constant.colorPrimary,
      ),
      centerTitle: true,
      elevation: 1.0,
      backgroundColor: constant.colorWhite),
  drawer: _drawerNav,
  body: _pageView,
  bottomNavigationBar: _bottomNav,
  floatingActionButton: _buildFloatingActionButton(),
  floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
)
```

SpeedDialFloatingActionButton.dart

````
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

// Special Thanks to Andrea Bizzotto and Matt Carroll!
//
// Goal: https://material.io/components/buttons-floating-action-button/#types-of-transitions
// Influenced by: https://medium.com/coding-with-flutter/flutter-adding-animated-overlays-to-your-app-e0bb049eff39
//                https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46480221/flutter-floating-action-button-with-speed-dail
// Codes from: https://github.com/bizz84/bottom_bar_fab_flutter
//             https://github.com/matthew-carroll/fluttery/blob/master/lib/src/layout_overlays.dart

class SpeedDialFloatingActionButton extends StatelessWidget {
  /// Creates Floating action button with speed dial attached.
  ///
  /// [childOnFold] is default widget attched to Floating action button.
  /// [useRotateAnimation] makes more fancy when using with Icons.add or with unfold child.
  ///
  /// The [childOnFold] must not be null. Additionally,
  /// if [childOnUnfold] is specified, two widgets([childOnFold] and [childOnUnfold]) will be switched with animation when speed dial is opened/closed.
  ///
  /// NOTE: In order to apply fade transition between [childOnFold] and [childOnUnfold], make sure one of those has Key field. (eg. ValueKey<int>(value) or UniqueKey()).
  ///       As we using AnimatedSwitcher for transition animation, no key with same type of child will perform no animation. It is AnimatedSwitcher's behaviour.
  SpeedDialFloatingActionButton(
      {@required this.actions,
        this.onAction,
        @required this.childOnFold,
        this.childOnUnfold,
        this.useRotateAnimation = false,
        this.backgroundColor,
        this.foregroundColor,
        this.screenColor,
        this.animationDuration = 250,
        this.controller,
        this.isDismissible = false,
        this.labelPosition});

  final List<SpeedDialAction> actions;
  final ValueChanged<int> onAction;
  final Widget childOnFold;
  final Widget childOnUnfold;
  final int animationDuration;
  final bool useRotateAnimation;
  final SpeedDialController controller;
  final bool isDismissible;

  /// The floating button's background color.
  ///
  /// If this property is null, then the [Theme]'s
  /// [ThemeData.floatingActionButtonTheme.backgroundColor] is used. If that
  /// property is also null, then the [Theme]'s
  /// [ThemeData.colorScheme.secondary] color is used.
  final Color backgroundColor;

  /// The floating button's foreground color.
  ///
  /// If this property is null, then the [Theme]'s
  /// [ThemeData.floatingActionButtonTheme.foregroundColor] is used. If that
  /// property is also null, then the [Theme]'s
  /// [ThemeData.colorScheme.onSecondary] color is used.
  final Color foregroundColor;

  /// The screen background color when the speed dial is unfolded.
  ///
  /// If this property is null, then the background will be transparent.
  /// Tip: use the opacity property to create semi-transparent backgrounds. Example:
  /// ```dart
  /// screenColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2)
  /// ```
  final Color screenColor;

  /// Define if the action's labels will be at the left or at the right of their action button.
  ///
  /// If this property is null, then the label position will obey the following rule:
  /// when the floating button is positioned before the middle of the display (on the x axis), the label will be at the right of the action button,
  /// otherwise the label will be at the left of the action button.
  final LabelPosition labelPosition;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnchoredOverlay(
      showOverlay: true,
      overlayBuilder: (context, offset) {
        return SpeedDial(
          controller: controller,
          actions: actions,
          onAction: onAction,
          childOnFold: childOnFold,
          childOnUnfold: childOnUnfold,
          animationDuration: animationDuration,
          useRotateAnimation: useRotateAnimation,
          backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
          foregroundColor: foregroundColor,
          screenColor: screenColor,
          isDismissible: isDismissible,
          offset: Offset(offset.dx, offset.dy),
          labelPosition: labelPosition,
        );
      },
      child: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {}),
    );
  }
}

class SpeedDialAction {
  SpeedDialAction(
      {this.child, this.label, this.backgroundColor, this.foregroundColor});

  final Widget child;
  final Widget label;

  /// The action button's background color.
  ///
  /// If this property is null, then the [Theme]'s
  /// [ThemeData.cardColor] is used.
  final Color backgroundColor;

  /// The action button's foreground color.
  ///
  /// If this property is null, then the [Theme]'s
  /// [ThemeData.accentColor] is used.
  final Color foregroundColor;
}

class SpeedDial extends StatefulWidget {
  SpeedDial({
    @required this.actions,
    this.onAction,
    @required this.childOnFold,
    this.childOnUnfold,
    this.animationDuration,
    this.useRotateAnimation,
    this.backgroundColor,
    this.foregroundColor,
    this.screenColor,
    this.controller,
    this.isDismissible,
    this.offset,
    this.labelPosition,
  });

  final SpeedDialController controller;
  final List<SpeedDialAction> actions;
  final ValueChanged<int> onAction;
  final Widget childOnFold;
  final Widget childOnUnfold;
  final int animationDuration;
  final bool useRotateAnimation;
  final Color screenColor;
  final Color backgroundColor;
  final Color foregroundColor;
  final bool isDismissible;
  final Offset offset;
  final LabelPosition labelPosition;

  @override
  State createState() => _SpeedDialState();
}

class _SpeedDialState extends State<SpeedDial> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: widget.animationDuration),
    );

    widget.controller ?? SpeedDialController()
      ..setAnimator(_controller);

    if (widget.isDismissible) {
      _controller.addStatusListener(_onDismissible);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildActions();
  }

  Widget _buildActions() {
    final Size fullsize = MediaQuery.of(context).size; // device size
    final double wButton = 28; // button width
    final double hButtom = 28; // button height

    double start;
    LabelPosition labelPosition = widget.labelPosition;
    if (labelPosition == null) {
      labelPosition = widget.offset.dx > (fullsize.width / 2)
          ? LabelPosition.Left
          : LabelPosition.Right;
    }
    if (labelPosition == LabelPosition.Right) {
      start = widget.offset.dx - wButton;
    } else {
      start = fullsize.width - widget.offset.dx - wButton;
    }

    double bottom;
    if (widget.offset.dy > (fullsize.height / 2)) {
      bottom = fullsize.height - widget.offset.dy - hButtom;
    } else {
      bottom = fullsize.height + (widget.offset.dy.abs() - hButtom);
    }

    return widget.screenColor != null
        ? _buildActionsWithOverlay(bottom, start, labelPosition)
        : _buildActionsWithoutOverlay(bottom, start, labelPosition);
  }

  Widget _buildActionsWithOverlay(
      [double bottom, double start, LabelPosition labelPosition]) {
    var screenColorSequence = TweenSequence<Color>([
      TweenSequenceItem(
          weight: 1.0,
          tween: ColorTween(
              begin: Color.fromARGB(0, 0, 0, 0), end: widget.screenColor))
    ]);

    return AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: _controller,
        builder: (context, child) {
          if (_controller.isDismissed == false)
            return GestureDetector(
                onTap: toggle,
                child: Container(
                    color: screenColorSequence
                        .evaluate(AlwaysStoppedAnimation(_controller.value)),
                    child: _buildActionsWithoutOverlay(
                        bottom, start, labelPosition)));
          else
            return _buildActionsWithoutOverlay(bottom, start, labelPosition);
        });
  }

  Widget _buildActionsWithoutOverlay(
      [double bottom, double start, LabelPosition labelPosition]) {
    return Stack(
      fit: StackFit.expand,
      children: <Widget>[
        Positioned.directional(
          textDirection: labelPosition == LabelPosition.Left
              ? TextDirection.rtl
              : TextDirection.ltr,
          bottom: bottom,
          start: start,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            crossAxisAlignment: labelPosition == LabelPosition.Left
                ? CrossAxisAlignment.end
                : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: List.generate(widget.actions.length, (int index) {
              return _buildChild(index, labelPosition);
            }).reversed.toList()
              ..add(
                _buildFab(),
              ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildChild(int index, LabelPosition labelPosition) {
    List<Widget> rowChildren = [
      _buildLabelAction(index),
      _buildChildAction(index),
    ];

    return Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: labelPosition == LabelPosition.Left
            ? rowChildren
            : rowChildren.reversed.toList());
  }

  Widget _buildLabelAction(int index) {
    return FadeTransition(
      opacity: Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1).animate(_controller),
      child: widget.actions[index].label != null
          ? Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0, horizontal: 8.0),
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.0, bottom: 20),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(6.0)),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.7),
              offset: Offset(0.8, 0.8),
              blurRadius: 2.4,
            )
          ],
        ),
        child: widget.actions[index].label,
      )
          : Container(),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildChildAction(int index) {
    Color backgroundColor =
        widget.actions[index].backgroundColor ?? Theme.of(context).cardColor;
    Color foregroundColor =
        widget.actions[index].foregroundColor ?? Theme.of(context).accentColor;

    return Container(
      height: 70.0,
      width: 56.0,
      alignment: FractionalOffset.topCenter,
      child: ScaleTransition(
        scale: CurvedAnimation(
          parent: _controller,
          curve: Interval(0.0, (index + 1) / widget.actions.length,
              curve: Curves.linear),
        ),
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
          foregroundColor: foregroundColor,
          mini: true,
          child: widget.actions[index].child,
          onPressed: () => _onAction(index),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildFab() {
    return FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: toggle,
      backgroundColor: widget.backgroundColor,
      foregroundColor: widget.foregroundColor,
      child:
      AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _controller,
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
        return Transform(
          transform:
          Matrix4.rotationZ(_controller.value * 0.5 * math.pi),
          alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
          child: Icon(
              _controller.isDismissed ? Icons.add : Icons.close),
        );
      },
    ),
      elevation: 2.0,
    );
  }

  void toggle() {
    if (_controller.isDismissed) {
      _controller.forward();
    } else {
      _controller.reverse();
    }
  }

  Widget _buildRotation(Widget child) {
    return Transform.rotate(
      angle: _controller.value * pi / 4,
      child: child,
    );
  }

  Widget _buildAnimatedSwitcher() {
    return AnimatedSwitcher(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: widget.animationDuration),
      child:
      _controller.value < 0.5 ? widget.childOnFold : widget.childOnUnfold,
    );
  }

  void _onAction(int index) {
    _controller.reverse();
    widget.onAction(index);
  }

  void _onDismissible(AnimationStatus status) {
    Future<bool> _onReturn() async {
      _controller.reverse();
      return false;
    }

    if (status == AnimationStatus.forward) {
      Navigator.of(context).push(
        PageRouteBuilder(
          fullscreenDialog: true,
          opaque: false,
          barrierDismissible: true,
          transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
          barrierColor: Colors.black54,
          pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, _, __) {
            return WillPopScope(
              child: Container(),
              onWillPop: _onReturn,
            );
          },
        ),
      );
    }
    if (status == AnimationStatus.reverse) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
    }
  }
}

enum LabelPosition { Left, Right }

class AnchoredOverlay extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool showOverlay;
  final Widget Function(BuildContext, Offset anchor) overlayBuilder;
  final Widget child;

  AnchoredOverlay({
    this.showOverlay,
    this.overlayBuilder,
    this.child,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      child: new LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
            return new OverlayBuilder(
              showOverlay: showOverlay,
              overlayBuilder: (BuildContext overlayContext) {
                RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
                final center =
                box.size.center(box.localToGlobal(const Offset(0.0, 0.0)));

                return overlayBuilder(overlayContext, center);
              },
              child: child,
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}

class OverlayBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool showOverlay;
  final Function(BuildContext) overlayBuilder;
  final Widget child;

  OverlayBuilder({
    this.showOverlay = false,
    this.overlayBuilder,
    this.child,
  });

  @override
  _OverlayBuilderState createState() => new _OverlayBuilderState();
}

class _OverlayBuilderState extends State<OverlayBuilder> {
  OverlayEntry overlayEntry;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    if (widget.showOverlay) {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => showOverlay());
    }
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(OverlayBuilder oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => syncWidgetAndOverlay());
  }

  @override
  void reassemble() {
    super.reassemble();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => syncWidgetAndOverlay());
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    if (isShowingOverlay()) {
      hideOverlay();
    }

    super.dispose();
  }

  bool isShowingOverlay() => overlayEntry != null;

  void showOverlay() {
    overlayEntry = new OverlayEntry(
      builder: widget.overlayBuilder,
    );
    addToOverlay(overlayEntry);
  }

  void addToOverlay(OverlayEntry entry) async {
    Overlay.of(context).insert(entry);
  }

  void hideOverlay() {
    overlayEntry.remove();
    overlayEntry = null;
  }

  void syncWidgetAndOverlay() {
    if (isShowingOverlay() && !widget.showOverlay) {
      hideOverlay();
    } else if (!isShowingOverlay() && widget.showOverlay) {
      showOverlay();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.child;
  }
}

class CenterAbout extends StatelessWidget {
  final Offset position;
  final Widget child;

  CenterAbout({
    this.position,
    this.child,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Positioned(
      top: position.dy,
      left: position.dx,
      child: new FractionalTranslation(
        translation: const Offset(-0.5, -0.5),
        child: child,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SpeedDialController extends ChangeNotifier {
  SpeedDialController();

  AnimationController _animationController;

  setAnimator(AnimationController controller) {
    _animationController = controller;
  }

  unfold() {
    if (_animationController.isDismissed == false) {
      _animationController.reverse();
    }
  }
}
````

Comment: Try changing the `elevation` property of `Drawer`,

Comment: @dev-aentgs i have tried that and it doesnt work

Comment: ok another way can be to wrap it with [Visibility](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Visibility-class.html) and set the `visible` property `false` when `Drawer` is shown and later reset to `true`. This is not an ideal solution. 
What happens when you change `elevation` property on the `Drawer` or on the `SpeedDial` ?

Comment: @dev-aentgs it looks like no changes. Thanks for the suggestion. Looks like i have to go with this one although it is not ideal

Comment: Raise a issue in their [issue tracker](https://github.com/fysoul17/flutter_speed_dial_material_design/issues), they might respond with some better workaround.