# Flutter Material Design FAB

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, material-design

It is possible to do a lot of elements with labels under FAB without any additional library? If not, what is the best library for this?

I talk about case from Material Design official documentation: https://material.io/components/buttons-floating-action-button#types-of-transitions
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it your self like this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46480722/11345007

or using this pub:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_speed_dial

Comment: thank You, 1st case looks nice, I try implement it