# How to manually show/dismiss DropdownButton in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I need more flexibility in presenting/dismissing a DropdownButton's list of choices in flutter. I want to be able to show/hide DropdownButton as a result of some other user action than clicking on it. It doesn't seem these methods are exposed in the doc. What is a good way to do this?

Comment: Are you talking about the whole widget or the icon?

Comment: The whole widget.

Comment: You could change the widget key and rebuild to hide it when it is opened, but that is not a great solution and does not work the other way round.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot that does indeed sound more like a hack.

Comment: I don't think there is a direct option for doing that.You can create a variable to control the state eg `child:(visible)?DropDownButton():Container()` and control the `visible` variable with `setState()`. when visibility is not needed, the empty container will be used. check out more options here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44489804/show-hide-widgets-on-flutter-programmatically

Comment: That is not the state for whether the dropdown list is showing or not, but rather it is the visibility of the entire dropdown button, which is not what I need.

Answer (score 1):

There is a specific widget for this:

Visibility(
  visible: false, 
  child: Container(color: Colors.blue, width: 100, height: 100),
),

Use visible to show or hide the widget, i.e isVisible().

Put whatever as a child, as example Column or Row.