# How do I hide SpeedDialChild from SpeedChild if bool condition false(Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am struggling to hide SpeedDialChild, when my **noDoctorReply == false**. I can't use if else conditions. I tried to code like below.

```
noDoctorReply == false
                  ? SpeedDialChild(
                      child: Icon(Icons.stop_screen_share_outlined),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                      label: 'Complete Conversation',
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                      onTap: () {
                        _completeDialog();
                      },
                    )
                  : SpeedDialChild(),
```

But it got me to here.
[image: Screenshot of above code result]

Is there any way to hide this? Thank you.

EDIT: I used package called **[flutter_speed_dial](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_speed_dial)**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use just `if` conditional state. While else is never needed to show up.

```dart
if(noDoctorReply) showMyWidget()
```

You can also check [`Visibility`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Visibility-class.html) widget.

Comment: Thank you, yes I can use that but when the condition true (noDoctorReply == true) I need to show that SpeedDialChild. When using if condition like that It won't show.

Comment: While you are using `if(value)` , means it will only show up when `value` is true. Is there something else happened after doing this?

Comment: yes. I use doctor and patient. When patient send message to the doctor, doctor can reply. And doctor has ability to complete conversation.  If doctor complete the conversation patient can't send new messages.  So I need to disable complete conversation button If doctor not replied at least one time to the patient. So I am checking if doctor replied to the patient, if so condition false (noDoctorReply = false).  If doctor not replied noDoctorReply = true. So I need to work this both ways.

Comment: check this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/68267115

Comment: Can you update the question including full widget that will reproduce the same issue?