# Display widget on Select and hide on Unselect flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a list which has select option:

```
GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    toggleIndexDay(sunIndex);
                                    confirmed = true;
                                  },
                                  child: Card(
```

and toggle instance:

```
void toggleIndexDay(int i) {
    if (selectionDayIndexes.contains(i))
      setState(() => selectionDayIndexes.remove(i));
    else
      setState(() => selectionDayIndexes.add(i));
  }
```

this allow me to select and unselect element in the list.
Now I have another instance called  `ConfirmSelection`
which Allow me to display a confirmation Button, but I dont know how to hide if in the List there is nothing Selected.
to display the button this is my code:

```
bool confirmed = false;
```

action on the button above with `confirmed = true;`
and in the widget:

```
floatingActionButton: (confirmed == true)
            ? FloatingActionButton( etc...
```

but how to hide if no item i the list is selected?

Comment: `floatingActionButton: confirmed == true  ? FloatingActionButton() : null`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show/hide widgets in Flutter programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44489804/show-hide-widgets-in-flutter-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

You can check if there's an item or not in the List with isEmpty or isNotEmpty properties.

```
floatingActionButton: selectionDayIndexes.isEmpty ? Container() : FloatingActionButton(),
```