# How to show/hide a widget based on the android sdk build version?

Tags: flutter

In an android app, we can use the `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` to get the SDK version of the software currently running on a hardware device. How to do the same in a flutter app so that I can show or hide a widget based on the android build version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [device_info](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info) plugin to get the SDK version:

```
var info = await DeviceInfoPlugin().androidInfo;
var sdk = info.version.sdkInt;
```

And then use it like

```
Column(
  children: [
    if (sdk > 24) Text('Good'), // Prints only for devices running API > 24
    Text('Morning')
  ],
)
```

If you don't want to use `if` you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53044562/6618622) for other options.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Device Info** Package to Get Device information

https://pub.dev/packages/device_info

You can get all of this information

```
var androidInfo = await DeviceInfoPlugin().androidInfo;

  var release = androidInfo.version.release;
  var sdkInt = androidInfo.version.sdkInt;
  var manufacturer = androidInfo.manufacturer;
  var model = androidInfo.model;

  print('Android $release (SDK $sdkInt), $manufacturer $model');
```

Answer (score 0):

[CopsOnRoad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66853905/220039) is good, however, when I only need the `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` from Android, and I already have `MethodChannel` implemented for other Android functionality that I need in Flutter, I prefer not to add an extra plugin.

I simply add the following (Java) code:

```java
case METHOD_GET_SDK_INT:
    result.success(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
    break;
```

in the MethodCall handler:

```java
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
    
    ...

    private static final String METHOD_GET_SDK_INT = "getSdkInt";

    @Override
    public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);
        new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(
                (call, result) -> {
                    switch (call.method) {
    
                    ...
                    
                    // New code for returning the Android SDK version
                    case METHOD_GET_SDK_INT:
                        result.success(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
                        break;

                    ...
```

Then, in Dart, I use:

```dart
final int _androidSdkInt = await platform.invokeMethod('getSdkInt');
```