# Flutter null safety conditional widget

Tags: flutter, dart

Before Flutter introduced the null-safety feature, I was able to conditionally add Widgets within a list like so:

```
actions: <Widget>[
  canCancel
    ? CupertinoDialogAction(
        child: Text(cancelActionText),
           onPressed: () {
             Navigator.pop(context);
           },
      )
    : null,
].where(notNull).toList()
```

`notNull` being a homemade filter that filters off the null objects...

Now with null-safety it's impossible because the list of Widgets strictly has to be non-null.
What would be a better approach?

Comment: add ? on canCancel so allows to have null

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just use `if` inside the `List`:

```
<Widget>[ 
   if (true) Widget(), 
]
```

Example with your code:

```
actions: <Widget>[
  if (canCancel)
    CupertinoDialogAction(
        child: Text(cancelActionText),
           onPressed: () {
             Navigator.pop(context);
           },
      ),
]
```

Comment: Wow is that something "new" you can do in Flutter? Didn't know about this!

Comment: @Scaraux Not really. It was something like Dart 2.5 or 2.6 or something. It's called a "collection if".

Answer (score 4):

Just replace your null with an empty, size zero, `SizedBox`.

```
SizedBox(width: 0, height: 0)
```

Or as suggested in comments:

```
SizedBox.shrink()
```

Comment: `SizedBox.shrink()` is the proper named constructor to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

As [YoBo suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67064312/), using [collection-`if`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#collection-operators) is the better approach here, but if for some reason you need to be able to store `null`s in a `List` and filter them out later (or if you just prefer your existing style), you can:

1. Change your `List` type to allow nullable elements.  That is, use `<Widget?>[]` instead of `<Widget>[]`.
2. Use `Iterable.whereType` with a non-nullable type to filter out `null` values.

```dart
actions: <Widget?>[
  canCancel
    ? CupertinoDialogAction(
        child: Text(cancelActionText),
           onPressed: () {
             Navigator.pop(context);
           },
      )
    : null,
].whereType<Widget>().toList();
```

Comment: This is a valid answer as well. I don't need to have null in the list though, the end goal was to conditionally insert the widget in a declarative manner. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`if` is not new as it was added in Dart 2.3 a few years ago. Even before null-safety, you were not allowed to return a `null` for a widget. You might not see a compile-time warning before NNBD, but it is a runtime error.

As I mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53044562/6618622) (although that answer isn't for your case), you can use `if` condition or even ternary operator like this:

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    if (condition) Text(''),
    condition ? Text('') : Container(),
  ],
)
```