# Is it possible to make the widget invisible when the Row widget overflows in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

[image]

it's flutter
I don't want to see textwidget4.
A row widget is at most one line.

I don't want to show the passed textwidget when the length of the row exceeds the SizedBox
What should I do?

Comment: The row widget should not be scrollable.

Comment: Do you know the size of the widgets beforehand?

Comment: yes  i use flutter_screenutil i set SizedBox width is 189.w

Comment: I meant the size of the text widgets, not the `SizedBox`. Do you have a default size for your `TextWidget`?

Comment: textwidget varies from time to time

Answer (score 0):

plaese look at https://pub.dev/packages/visibility_detector

I think with this library you can Understand which widget is not Completely Visible . (`visiblePercentage`)

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return VisibilityDetector(
    key: Key('my-widget-key'),
    onVisibilityChanged: (visibilityInfo) {
      var visiblePercentage = visibilityInfo.visibleFraction * 100;
      debugPrint(
          'Widget ${visibilityInfo.key} is ${visiblePercentage}% visible');
    },
    child: someOtherWidget,
  );
}
```

#### second Step

[Show/hide widgets in Flutter programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44489804/show-hide-widgets-in-flutter-programmatically)