# How to show/hide widgets but occupy space programmatically in Flutter

Tags: flutter

A widget need to exist in a Row. But need to hide. Visibilty widget won't work because it would not occupy the space. How to make this work in Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the below answer you can use the Opacity widget in Flutter.
Wrap the required widget with an Opacity widget.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44489903/7870443