# How to only display the ListView when taping on the TextField

Tags: flutter, listview, textfield

I have the suggestions list displayed on the screen by default, and I would like to make the suggestions list shows only when clicking on the text field.

I tried to put the listView in side the setState, but it did not work. I also tried to make a controller listener, but also did not work. Should I wrap the listView with a button?

Any help please!

here is my code

```
class MySearchBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const MySearchBar({super.key});

  @override
  State<MySearchBar> createState() => _MySearchBarState();
}

class _MySearchBarState extends State<MySearchBar> {
  final myController = TextEditingController();
  static List<RestaurantProfiles> searchList = mySearchList;

  List<RestaurantProfiles> display_list = List.from(searchList);

  // this is the function that will update the suggestion list while searching
  void searchUpdate(String value) {
    setState(() {
      display_list = searchList
          .where((element) => element.restaurantName
              .toLowerCase()
              .contains(value.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          TextField(
            onChanged: (value) => searchUpdate(value),
            style: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              filled: true,
              fillColor: Colors.white,
              isDense: true,
              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                borderSide: BorderSide.none,
              ),
              hintText: "Add Restaurants",
              hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black26,
              ),
              prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.search),
              prefixIconColor: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 5,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 250,
            child: Expanded(
              child: display_list.isEmpty
                  ? const Center(
                      child: Text(
                        "oops... No Results Found!",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  : Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          color: Colors.white70),
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: display_list.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                          title: Text(display_list[index].restaurantName),
                          leading: Image(
                            image: AssetImage(display_list[index].img),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            height: 50,
                            width: 50,
                          ),
                          trailing: const Icon(Icons.add),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample based on your code. I hope this will resolve the issue.

```
class MySearchBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const MySearchBar({super.key});

  @override
  State<MySearchBar> createState() => _MySearchBarState();
}

class _MySearchBarState extends State<MySearchBar> {
  final myController = TextEditingController();
  // static List<RestaurantProfiles> searchList = mySearchList;
  final mySearchList = ['abc', 'xyz', 'cvb'];
  List display_list = [];

  // this is the function that will update the suggestion list while searching
  void searchUpdate(String value) {
    setState(() {
      display_list = mySearchList
          .where(
              (element) => element.toLowerCase().contains(value.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();
    });
  }

  FocusNode node = FocusNode();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    node.addListener(() {
      showList = node.hasFocus;
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  bool showList = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: textEditingController,
              focusNode: node,
              onChanged: (value) => searchUpdate(value),
              style: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                filled: true,
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                isDense: true,
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                ),
                hintText: "Add Restaurants",
                hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black26,
                ),
                prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                prefixIconColor: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 5,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 250,
              child: Expanded(
                child: showList || textEditingController.text.isNotEmpty
                    ? display_list.isEmpty
                        ? const Center(
                            child: Text(
                              "oops... No Results Found!",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20,
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        : Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                color: Colors.white70),
                            child: ListView.builder(
                              itemCount: display_list.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                title: Text(display_list[index]),
                                // leading: Image(
                                //   image: AssetImage(display_list[index].img),
                                //   fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                //   height: 50,
                                //   width: 50,
                                // ),
                                trailing: const Icon(Icons.add),
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                    : Text('Search for restaurant'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is also working. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'd like to mention that you'd probably want to use a [`SearchDelegate`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SearchDelegate-class.html) instead - as it can suggest the results for completion.

You can use a [`FocusNode`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FocusNode-class.html) to listen to changes. it detects when the TextField does/desn't have focus.

At your State class, create 3 variables:

```dart
class _MySearchBarState extends State<MySearchBar> {
  final myController = TextEditingController();
  final _focusNode = FocusNode();
  var _isSearching = false;
```

Then, create an `initState` method:

```dart
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _focusNode.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        _isSearching = _focusNode.hasFocus;
      });
    });
  }
```

And in your listview.builder:

```dart
Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        color: Colors.white70),
                    child: _isSearching
                        ? ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: display_list.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return Text(
                                'test',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                              );
                              return ListTile(
                                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                title: Text(display_list[index].restaurantName),
                                leading: Image(
                                  image: AssetImage(display_list[index].img),
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  height: 50,
                                  width: 50,
                                ),
                                trailing: const Icon(Icons.add),
                              );
                            },
                          )
                        : Container(),
                  )
```

---

Complete runnable snippet:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Material App Bar'),
        ),
        body: MySearchBar(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MySearchBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const MySearchBar({super.key});

  @override
  State<MySearchBar> createState() => _MySearchBarState();
}

class _MySearchBarState extends State<MySearchBar> {
  final myController = TextEditingController();
  final _focusNode = FocusNode();
  var _isSearching = false;
  static List<RestaurantProfiles> searchList = [
    RestaurantProfiles('test', 'assets/images/restaurant1.jpg'),
  ];

  List<RestaurantProfiles> display_list = List.from(searchList);

  // this is the function that will update the suggestion list while searching
  void searchUpdate(String value) {
    setState(() {
      display_list = searchList
          .where((element) => element.restaurantName
              .toLowerCase()
              .contains(value.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          TextField(
            focusNode: _focusNode,
            onChanged: (value) => searchUpdate(value),
            style: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              filled: true,
              fillColor: Colors.white,
              isDense: true,
              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                borderSide: BorderSide.none,
              ),
              hintText: "Add Restaurants",
              hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black26,
              ),
              prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.search),
              prefixIconColor: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 5,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: display_list.isEmpty
                ? const Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "oops... No Results Found!",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                : Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        color: Colors.white70),
                    child: _isSearching
                        ? ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: display_list.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return Text(
                                'test',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                              );
                              return ListTile(
                                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                title: Text(display_list[index].restaurantName),
                                leading: Image(
                                  image: AssetImage(display_list[index].img),
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  height: 50,
                                  width: 50,
                                ),
                                trailing: const Icon(Icons.add),
                              );
                            },
                          )
                        : Container(),
                  ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _focusNode.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        _isSearching = _focusNode.hasFocus;
      });
    });
  }
}

class RestaurantProfiles {
  final String restaurantName;
  final String img;

  RestaurantProfiles(this.restaurantName, this.img);
}
```

**Relatable**

- [How to show/hide widgets programmatically in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44489804/12349734)

Comment: That works very well. Thank you for the help