# Show and hide input field when select radio button

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I set text field and show and hide text based on radio button. I want to set when select yes text and text field will be visible and when deselect yes text and text field will be hidden. I tried to find info in this regard but was unsuccessful.

[image: Screenshot]

My code:

```
bool select = false;
 String _medicalhistory = "n/a";
Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 800
                ? 700
                : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    const Text(
                      "Past medical history: ",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 14,
                          height: 1.5),
                    ),
                    RadioListTile(
                      title: const Text("Yes"),
                      value: "yes",
                      groupValue: _medicalhistory,
                      //onChanged: handleSelection
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _medicalhistory = value!;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    const Text(
                        "If yes, please share and describe the previous medical illness: "),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 5,
                    ),
                    TextField(
                      controller: myController,
                      maxLength: 1000,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        //hintText: 'Enter a search term',
                      ),
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        TextButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              _medicalhistory = myController.text;
                            },
                            child: const Text("Save")),
                      ],
                    ),
                    RadioListTile(
                      title: const Text("No"),
                      value: "no",
                      groupValue: _medicalhistory,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _medicalhistory = value.toString();
                        });
                      },
                    ),

                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

I am attaching the code if anyone is willing to help me. Sorry, I'm new to this. Please guide me and I hope someone is willing to share the code on how to make the design I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple, check for your condition and use an `if`.

In this example, were using the [spread operator](https://dart.dev/language/collections#spread-operators) (`...`) to add multiple items to show in the list:

For example:

```
if (_medicalhistory == "yes")...[
    TextField()
    AnotherWidgetWhenConditionIsYes()
    ...
  ]
```

Your complete code would look like:

```dart
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 800
          ? 700
          : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          const Text(
            "Past medical history: ",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 14, height: 1.5),
          ),
          RadioListTile(
            title: const Text("Yes"),
            value: "yes",
            groupValue: _medicalhistory,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _medicalhistory = value.toString();
              });
            },
          ),
          // use if statement to show the textfield only when the value is yes
          if (_medicalhistory == "yes") ...[
            const Text("If yes, please share and describe the previous medical illness: "),
            const SizedBox(height: 5),
            TextField(
              controller: myController,
              maxLength: 1000,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _medicalhistory = myController.text;
                  },
                  child: const Text("Save"),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
          RadioListTile(
            title: const Text("No"),
            value: "no",
            groupValue: _medicalhistory,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _medicalhistory = value.toString();
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

**See also**

- [How to show/hide widgets programmatically in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44489804/12349734)

Answer (score 0):

Use turnery operator or if to see if `medicalhistory == "Yes"` then display textbox

```
 String medicalhistory = "No";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
   body: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 800 ? 700 : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                const Text(
                  "Past medical history: ",
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 14, height: 1.5),
                ),
                RadioListTile(
                  title: const Text("Yes"),
                  value: "Yes",
                  groupValue: medicalhistory,
                  //onChanged: handleSelection
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      medicalhistory = value!;
                    });
                  },
                ),
                medicalhistory == "Yes"
                    ? Column(
                        children: [
                          const Text("If yes, please share and describe the previous medical illness: "),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                          TextField(
                            controller: myController,
                            maxLength: 1000,
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                              //hintText: 'Enter a search term',
                            ),
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                            children: [
                              TextButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    medicalhistory = myController.text;
                                  },
                                  child: const Text("Save")),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    : const SizedBox(),
                RadioListTile(
                  title: const Text("No"),
                  value: "No",
                  groupValue: medicalhistory,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      medicalhistory = value!;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
     )
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ValueNotifier` which will `rebuild` only specific widget

```
final ValueNotifier<bool> showText = ValueNotifier<bool>(false);

   RadioListTile(
                  title: const Text("Yes"),
                  value: "Yes",
                  groupValue: medicalhistory,
                  //onChanged: handleSelection
                  onChanged: (value) {
                   showText.value=value;
                  },
                ),



ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
          builder:  (context, value, _) {
              return value?Column( 
                   children:[
                      const Text(
                    "If yes, please share and describe the previous medical 
                             illness: "),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 5,
                ),
                TextField(
                  controller: myController,
                  maxLength: 1000,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    //hintText: 'Enter a search term',
                  ),
                ),
                         ]
                       ):const SizedBox.shrink() ;
             }),
```