# How to make the Selection visible on ToogleButton / Flutter

Tags: flutter

Idk why but also if I follow the flutter dev guide I can't do it in the correct mode, also I want to take the value inside the switch into a variable that can I use in an external code to send this data to database.

BTW also if on print it take correctly the true and false index on the debug he not change the color of the corrext index

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get/get_core/src/get_main.dart';

import '../Modelli/immProfilo.dart';
import '../services/Database.dart';



class Prenotazione extends StatefulWidget {
  const Prenotazione({super.key});

  @override
  State<Prenotazione> createState() => _PrenotazioneState();
}

class _PrenotazioneState extends State<Prenotazione> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int _scelta;
    final controlloIm = Get.put(ImagePickerController());
    final String uid = auth.currentUser!.uid;
    final List<bool> _tempoSelezionato = <bool>[true, false, false];
    bool vertical = false;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Prenotazione',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 24,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
              color: Colors.white,
            )),
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xffE5332A),
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 175,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0xFFE5332A),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
              ),
            ),
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/profilo');
              },
              child: StreamBuilder(
                  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection('utenti')
                      .where('uid', isEqualTo: uid)
                      .snapshots(),
                  // stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('utenti').snapshots(),

                  builder: (BuildContext context,
                      AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                      return const Text('Caricamento');
                    } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      List docs = snapshot.data!.docs;
                      final String uid = auth.currentUser!.uid;
                      return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                          var doc = snapshot.data!.docs[i];
                          var data = doc.data() as Map;
                          // return Text('${data['Nome']}');
                          return ListTile(
                            leading: SizedBox(
                                width: 50,
                                height: 50,
                                child: controlloIm.image.value.path == 'null'
                                    ? CircleAvatar(
                                        // backgroundImage: NetworkImage('$userPhoto')),
                                        backgroundImage: AssetImage(
                                            'images/utente-predefinito.jpg'))
                                    : CircleAvatar(
                                        // backgroundImage: NetworkImage('$userPhoto')),
                                        backgroundImage:
                                            NetworkImage('${data['url']}'))),
                            title: Text(
                              '${data['Nome']}',
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                fontSize: 18,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                            subtitle: const SizedBox(
                              width: 100,
                              height: 20,
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Icon(
                                        Icons.circle,
                                        color: Colors.green,
                                        size: 10,
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        width: 7,
                                      ),
                                      Text('Online',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                          )),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    }
                    return const Text('Qualcosa è andato storto');
                  }),
            ),
          ),
          Stack(children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: Container(
                height: 420,
                width: 500,
                transform: Matrix4.translationValues(0.0, -110.0, 0.0),
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(20),
                  ),
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage('images/sfondo.png'),
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.15),
                      spreadRadius: 5,
                      blurRadius: 7,
                      offset: Offset(0, 3),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      const Text(
                        'Prenota il tuo turno',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xFFE5332A),
                          fontSize: 24,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Di quanto tempo avrai bisogno in bagno?',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      SingleChildScrollView(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        child: ToggleButtons(
                            onPressed: (int newindex) {
                              setState(() {
                                 for (int i = 0; i < _tempoSelezionato.length; i++) {
                                   _tempoSelezionato[i] = i == newindex;
                                   switch(newindex){
                                     case 0:
                                       _scelta = 5;
                                       break;
                                     case 1:
                                       _scelta = 10;
                                       break;
                                     case 2:
                                       _scelta = 15;
                                       break;
                                   }
                                 }
                              });
                            },
                          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                          selectedBorderColor: Color(0xFF0E8639),
                          selectedColor: Colors.white,
                          fillColor: Color(0xFF0E8639),
                          color: Color(0xFF787878),
                            constraints: const BoxConstraints(
                              minHeight: 50.0,
                              minWidth: 120.0,
                            ),
                          isSelected: _tempoSelezionato,
                          children: [
                            Text('5 minuti'),
                            Text('10 minuti'),
                            Text('15 minuti'),
                          ],

                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      Text(
                          '* Ricordati che una volta che avrai prenotato il bagno dovrai aspettare il tuo turno ed una volta concluso confermarlo nell’app con l’apposito pulsante di modo che possa andare la persona successiva.'),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: (){},
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                            minimumSize: Size(250, 50),
                          ),
                          child: Text('Conferma la prenotazione', style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                            fontSize: 18,
                          ),)),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ]),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: is this solve your question [how-to-show-hide-widgets-programmatically-in-flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44489804/how-to-show-hide-widgets-programmatically-in-flutter)

Comment: No man…unfortunally no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have `_tempoSelezionato` inside the `build` method, so it will get reinitialized with its default value every time the widget rebuilds. Move it outside the `build` method to `_PrenotazioneState` like this:

```dart
class _PrenotazioneState extends State<Prenotazione> {
  final List<bool> _tempoSelezionato = <bool>[true, false, false];
  
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I man, I try thanks! And also, for the int value inside Switch? I try to get the variable out of that but not pass the value :(

Comment: Same thing, move `_scelta` out of the `build` method. Basically every state variable has to be outside the `build` method

Comment: Man!! Thanks a lot! It works! also for the choice inside the switch, is the same problem at the end, I'm really idiot! 
Thanks a lot!

Sorry I try also to do something like that but idk if is possible, I need to make a value that autoincrement when it clicked, but the real problem that is have to auto increase for the single uid but related with the other documents. 
To be clear, if user have this value on 1 user1 need to have it on 2 and so on...is possible?

Comment: Yes, I'm new also on Stack, when I understand How to accept your answer I make it for sure man! Thanks a lot!